# How to iterate over multiple regex matches and replace them?

Tags: python, html, regex

**Replace each sentence containing the word fear, with the same sentence, wrapped in a b tag with class="fear".**

Trying to wrap each (of 2 total) matches for this pattern in html tags.

```
import re
with open('chicken.txt', 'r') as file:
pattern = re.compile(r'[^\.]+fear[^\.]+')
text = file.read()
matches = pattern.finditer(text)
tagstart = '<b class="fear">'
tagend = '</b>'

replacement = [text.replace(match[0], tagstart + match[0] + tagend) for match in matches]

with open('chick.html', 'w') as htmlfile:
    htmlfile.write(replacement[0])
```

chick.html output looks like this:

```
If you've spent much time with chickens, you may doubt their ability to process a thought as complex as
"Chicken A will beat me anyway, so why bother to fight?" Your doubt is well placed.
Pecking orders are yet another case where the "thinking" has been done by natural selection,
and so needn't be done by the organism.<b class="fear"> The organism must be able to tell its neighbors apart,
and to feel a healthy fear of the ones that have brutalized it, but it needn't grasp the logic behind the fear</b>.
Any genes endowing a chicken with this selective fear, reducing the time spent in futile and costly combat, should flourish.
```

The final sentence is the second item in the replacement variable, and in isn't wrapped in that b tag.

Comment: Please remove the image and instead include sample input and output, both formatted as text.

Comment: But it's got html tags in it which won't format correctly

Comment: If you format it as code, with four lines in front, it will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over each `match` from `findinter` using replace but performing the substitution over the whole text each time.

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'[^\.]+fear[^\.]+')
tagstart = '<b class="fear">'
tagend = '</b>'

with open('chicken.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()
    matches = pattern.finditer(text)

    for match in matches:
        text = text.replace(match[0], tagstart + match[0] + tagend)

with open('chick.html', 'w') as htmlfile:
    htmlfile.write(text)
```

File *chick.html*

```html
If you've spent much time with chickens, you may doubt their ability to process a
 thought as complex as "Chicken A will beat me anyway, so why bother to fight?" Your doubt 
is well placed. Pecking orders are yet another case where the "thinking" has been done by natural 
selection, and so needn't be done by the organism.<b class="fear"> The organism must be able to tell 
its neighbors apart, and to feel a healthy fear of the ones that have brutalized it, but 
it needn't grasp the logic behind the fear</b>.<b class="fear"> Any genes endowing a chicken with 
this selective fear, reducing the time spent in futile and costly combat, should flourish</b>.
```

Comment: Works perfect. tysm!